# IIS not recognizing my pages

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

For some reason IIS 7 for Windows Server 2008 is not recognizing my pages I am able to install a single page called index.php with phpinfo(); in it and it will display the code perfectly fine. However, when I go to a page like /quickstart/register, it gives off the "404 - File or directory not found."

Can someone please explain some things or fixes for this?

Here is my webconfig file: http://pastebin.com/0jrumGmv

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have a rewrite module then I can't see how it's going to find pages like `/quickstart/register`.

Comment: Here's my URL rewrite (web.config) file: http://pastebin.com/0jrumGmv

Comment: I would update your question with that information as it's pretty important. My advice would be to start off with 1 single rule, get it working, then move onto each individually.

Answer (score 0):

You either need URL Rewrite rules set up properly or if your PHP app does routing from its index,php then check your PHP application code.

I am unable to see your web.config file (Access Blocked in office to pastebin :-) ) but if you can paste the URL rewrite section then I may be able to check it out hopefully.

If you are using a standard PHP framework or application they usually have good documentation on URL rewrite if needed. However, they are also good resources for duplicating it for your app.

For Example, I have seen people replicate wordpress's URL rewrite documentation for their applications.

Answer (score -1):

I understood that you try execute php file in Windows Server 2008. But, Windows Server isn't compatible with PHP. Windows Server is compatible with ASP, ASP.NET. But you can execute PHP files in Windows with using WAMP server. http://www.wampserver.com/en/ But , it can't be stable. I think you should use Linux Hosting for your PHP files and sites to get the best performance.

Comment: No, I simply use IIS 7 to host the website and then I download MySQL and PHP5 from Windows Platform installer. It goes live fine, it's just the issue I am having.

Comment: @James yes it can host PHP but I know that WAMP server must be installed for it, musn't be?
EDIT: Sorry, I dont know IIS 7 can host PHP.